# atexit() undefined with freestanding CLang

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, atexit

I'm trying to compile and link some C++ code using CLang, with the following command line:

```
clang.exe -nostdinc -MD -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fsigned-char -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -m64 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-ignored-attributes
```

(I left out the output, includes, defines, etc. These are fine)

The issue I'm having is that during linking, I get the error

```
error: L0039: reference to undefined symbol `atexit'
```

I've spent quite some time on this issue already, but can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to properly resolve this.

My research so far has shown that **atexit** is defined in *stdlib.h*, but I can not use the standard library in this situation (this isn't my decision either, and is completely mandatory for this particular project).

As far as I can tell this issue is only now arising due to the fact that we now suddenly have static objects in our code which is compiled this way, which leads the compiler trying to register con/destructors to be executed for these objects, which requires a call to **__cxa_atexit** (which we've disabled because it was also giving undefined reference errors because of the same reason) or **atexit**.

I've also tried defining an arbitrary **atexit** function in my code, but apparently the linker doesn't want to have anything to do with this (which does seem rather strange to me).

So the question I have is: How can I get the linker to not whine about **atexit**, while not having to include the standard library?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: "I've also tried defining an arbitrary atexit function in my code, but apparently the linker doesn't want to have anything to do with this (which does seem rather strange to me)." - perhaps you forgot to declare it as 'extern "C"'?

Comment: Hmm, I believe that was actually the first thing I tried, but im not 100% sure. I'll give that a go once I'm back in the office! (Here's hoping this will actually resolve it) in the meantime I welcome any and all other suggestions anyone might have by the way, the more options I have, the better.

Comment: It seems I forgot to add **extern "C"** to the definition of **atexit** (I only added it to the declaration), this seems to have resolved the issue! Thanks everyone who replied, and thank you davmac for providing the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future visitors, user [damvac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388661/davmac) was able to help out!

Here's my comment about the issue being resolved:

> It seems I forgot to add extern "C" to the definition of atexit (I only added it to the declaration), this seems to have resolved the issue! Thanks everyone who replied, and thank you davmac for providing the solution!

Answer (score 0):

`atexit` (and the whole concept of "exiting" in general) do not exist in a freestanding environment, so you can't call it in your code.

To get the compiler to not generate support code that calls it, you need to compile all your source files with `-ffreestanding` to specify that you are using/generating freestanding code.

Comment: I believe the problem is that g++ generates a call to `atexit`, not that the OP was calling `atexit`; furthermore I don't think using `-ffreestanding` will help, as the compiler must still register destruction of statically initialised variables somehow.

Comment: davmac, you are correct. Our code isn't calling **atexit** itself, rather the compiler inserts these calls to destruct static objects (but I think Chris Dodd also understood this).

I did try using -ffreestanding anyway, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.